# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. Fetch Function VueJS

Tags: javascript, json, function, vue.js, fetch

Guys i'm having trouble using this fetch function

```
fetchWeather() {
    fetch(`${this.url_base}weather?q=${this.query}&units=metric&APPID=${this.api_key}`)
    .then(res => {
      return res.json()
    }).then(this.setResults)
  },
  setResults(results) {
    this.weather = results
  },
```

It says "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `Unexpected < in JSON` usually means you actually hit XML or HTML. If you return `res.text()` instead of `.json()` and log that out, you'll see which it was. You should also probably set the correct `accept` head to signify that you want JSON back.